# emulate old mac OS X version on Mac

Tags: macos, emulation, osx-yosemite

Is there a way to emulate (legally) an older MAC OS X prior to 10.10 on a Mac OS X 10.10? I want to test my apps on older OS and I want to recreate all the possible conditions